# "wouldn't worry none"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is the usage of the word "none" correct here? It can't mean "at all", as far as I know (and I checked it on Lexico)

> I keep hearin' you're concerned about my happiness
>
> But all that thought you're givin' me is conscience I guess
>
> If I were walkin' in your shoes, I wouldn't worry **none**
>
> While you and your friends are worried about me, I'm havin' lots of fun

Comment: Yes, 'none' can mean 'at all' in US (Southern) regional rural dialect.

Comment: It isn't 'correct' in standard English, but this isn't standard English (as evidenced by the participles [-ing] with the 'g' dropped).

Comment: These are quotes from colloquial/dialect speech, most likely Sourthern US.  They aren't standard English. This doesn't make it "wrong" though.  In standard English it would be "I wouldn't worry at all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'none' can mean 'at all' in US (Southern) regional rural dialect.

So, while it isn't 'correct' in standard English, this isn't standard English (as evidenced by the participles [-ing] with the 'g' dropped).